# Index and match #VALUE! Between two worksheets

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]
[[image: MERCH.]][[image: ]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqore.png)I have created a drop list using match formula. This works. I have a list of users, and the drop down of months. I need to be able to select the month and see the score for each user. This is the formula I type: INDEX(MERCH.!Q18:X21,Worksheet!O11:O12)

Q18:X21 contain the scores in numbers. O11:O12 are the cells containing the MATCH formula. They match to the list of users, and the drop list of months.

This gives me #VALUE!  How do I correct this so that when select a month, it shows the value itself?

Comment: INDEX function needs Row Number and optionally Column number as numeric arguments. If the values in Worksheet!O11:O12 are text, it would return #VALUE! Error. Additionally also note that you are passing a range as Row reference to INDEX. Normally if it's not an Array Formula only the first reference shall be considered for evaluation. You may like to show us  screenshot of your sample data. Also I assume 'MERCH.' is a name of your Worksheet.

Comment: Just edit your question to include the relevant images. No need to delete it. Also did you check if the values in O11:O12 are numeric or text? Is there a dot . after MERCH in the worksheet name, as it's seen in your formula?

Comment: It appears that you have taken photographs of the screen. I suggest that you use Print Screen button on your keyboard and take a better snapshot, save it as image format and update in your question.

Comment: Edited once more.